# Visiting South Africa twice for 90 days while I wait for my study permit?

Tags: visas, south-africa, dutch-citizens

I am a student in South Africa but I am not from there, in fact, I am from The Netherlands. I would like to know if I can get a visitor's visa twice for 90 days, having the first one expired I want to know if I can just enter the country again without applying for another one which takes a long time. I have been waiting for my study permit for ages and can't just be out of the country without attending classes.

Comment: so to clarify, wouldn't studying on a visitor visa be breaking the law?

Comment: basically yes, but i wont be able to attend classes, just drive in daily to recieve my work, this ive been doing the whole of the first semester.

Comment: do you know the answer to my question or no?

Comment: I don't, I'm just trying to clarify what you're doing for when those who know more than me come by to help.

Comment: To clarify: how would you re-enter? By plane, boat, or car? My answer might change if you enter by car, though I doubt it. It would also mean visas to other African countries.

Comment: i left by plane a day ago and plan to re enter by car or bus

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find anything that says you can't, and it would be highly unusual if you couldn't. The exemption you get as a Dutch citizen allows you to [enter SA without a visa](http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/immigration-services/exempt-countries) as you know, though the rules of your stay seem to be the same as if you got a 90 day visitors permit under section 31(3)(b)[Accredited in SA] - (for the record, I can't actually seem to find the text of this section anywhere). Thus, you should have no issues simply leaving the country (most countries require you leave for at least 24 hours) and then returning to get a new visa.

To double check I think your best bet is to either call the [Dutch embassy in SA](http://southafrica.nlembassy.org/), or the [SA embassy in The Netherlands](http://www.zuidafrika.nl/south-african-embassy-consular-faqs#visas). Either should be able to give you a solid answer.

Please also note, that while you might legally be allowed to re-enter for another 90 days, an SA immigration officer could well question you about your past entry and why you are entering again so soon. Your visa exemption is also valid for most business purposed though, so you'll probably be alright.

Comment: this might be the best answer i could have recieved, thank you for the information, i will contct the embassy as soon as possible and go on from there. thank you for the effort, god bless you.

Comment: Sure thing :) Let us know what they say!

Comment: Are you confident that 1) It's OK to take a six month course of study without a student visa 2) it's actually OK to do 2 back to back visits, even if you leave for 24 hours. Most countries have rules preventing both of those.

Comment: @DJClayworth I am almost positive that what the OP is doing regarding studying on a visitors permit is **not legal**. However, that is not the question at hand. Most countries allow you to "enter" again after a 24 hour period on a new visa.

Comment: Not Schengen and not the US.

Comment: You are slightly incorrect. The Schengen countries and the US have a restriction on re-entering the area without a visa (for example, as a US citizen, I can enter visa-free into Schengen once every 6 months, and then stay for up to 3 months). However, you are free to re-enter the area with a valid visa at any time.

Comment: [The Schengen 90/180 rule applies to both visa-free stays and those with visas.](http://www.euro-dollar-currency.com/90_180_days_rule.htm). Obviously there are also visas that permit longer stays, but that's the rule for standard tourist visas.